# ROS Groovy Gazebo cannot spawn objects

Tags: groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am just trying to spawn objects and I have just copied two commands from tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API
Both give same exact errors. I have tried with multipe model files under gazebo_worlds/objects/*.model but they all seems to give same errors below.

```
1.  rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/desk1.model -gazebo -model desk1 -x 0
2.  rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/000.580.67.model -gazebo -model cup -z 2

Warning [parser.cc:374] Gazebo SDF has no <gazebo> element in file[data-string]
[ERROR] [1358995976.958104948, 86.064000000]: Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
Error [parser_urdf.cc:1659] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Warning [parser.cc:374] Gazebo SDF has no <gazebo> element in file[urdf string]
Error [parser.cc:318] parse as old urdf model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1190] Unable to read sdf string
```

I am not able to spawn any objects that came with ROS Groovy.
Are these model files outdated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1067/ros-groovy-gazebo-cannot-spawn-objects/) by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138/r0nald/) on 2013-01-28**:
I have a similar problem. The models should be fine, because Gazebo can load them from model directory or if they are embedded from world. It is juts spawn_model node of ROS that can't load the model.

My question in ROS QA: http://answers.ros.org/question/52076/gazebo-sdf-model-loading-in-groovy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just looked at the `.model` files in `gazebo_worlds` in groovy. They are all from Gazebo < 1.0, and are longer supported.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-25**:
Nate, while your attention is on SDF problems, have you seen this: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/854/error-loading-sdf-in-gazebo-131/ ? There's a good workaround proposed, but I think the original problem stems from a bug.

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on 2013-01-26**:
Okay. Why is none of the supported model files included in ROS Groovy? Accoridng to http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/beginner/build_world Gazebo 1.2 documentation, it should have objects appear under "Insert" Tab, but none appears in ROS Gazebo.. Is this a known issue?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-01-28**:
@ps for version 1.2.5 you can insert them if they are in ~/.gazebo/models folder, I couldn't manage to set the paths so they can be seen from other folders. Maybe it is fixed on newer versions.